# Why am I getting a 'not unique' error when referencing a primary key?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, sqlalchemy-migrate

I have two models -

Station:

```
class Station(db.Model):
    """Measurement station"""
    __tablename__ = "station"

    reference = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    status = db.Column(db.Text)


    river_analyses = db.relationship("RiverAnalysis")
```

and

RiverAnalysis:

```
class RiverAnalysis(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "river_analysis"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    reference = db.Column(db.Text, db.ForeignKey("station.reference"), nullable=False)

    station_ref = db.relationship("Station", foreign_keys=reference)
```

When I try to run `flask db upgrade` using this migration code

```
def upgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.add_column('river_analysis', sa.Column('reference', sa.Text(), nullable=False))
    op.create_foreign_key(None, 'river_analysis', 'station', ['reference'], ['reference'])
```

I get this error: `(psycopg2.ProgrammingError) there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "station"`.

Why am I getting this even though `station.reference` is a primary key of `Station`?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Do you have a "composite" primary key consisting of `reference, name` by design, or did you mean to make `name` unique on its own?

Answer (score 1):

`reference` alone is not your primary key, but the pair `(reference, name)`. In order to reference that key you need a [composite foreign key constraint](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/constraints.html#defining-foreign-keys):

```
class RiverAnalysis(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "river_analysis"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    reference = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    name = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)

    __table_args__ = (
        db.ForeignKeyConstraint(
            [reference, name],
            ["station.reference", "station.name"]),
    )
```